# postgresql: INSERT INTO … (SELECT * …,"fixed value")

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following is an example for the requirement I have.I have 2 tables. User table and another table where I enter the food user likes.

```
Class User{
    long id
}

class UserFood{
    Long id (auto-generated)
    long user_id
    String food
}
```

In my db I have a few hundred records. Now I want to take all the user's from UserFood table who have the food "French Toast" and add "Orange Juice"

So i'm looking for an insert statement like the following

```
insert into user_food (user_id,food) values (select user_id from user_food where food="French Toast","Orange Juice");
```

When i run the above query i get the following error

```
syntax error at or near "select"
```

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to use a `select` don't use `values`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will add orange juice records for all users who have at least one french toast record.

```
INSERT INTO user_food (user_id, food)
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 'Orange Juice'
FROM user_food
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_food WHERE food = 'French Toast')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the solution with a slight modification to our answer : `INSERT INTO user_food (user_id, food)
SELECT distinct user_id, 'Orange Juice'
FROM user_food
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT distinct  user_id FROM user_food WHERE food = 'French Toast')`

Comment: @Visahan You don't need `DISTINCT` in the subquery, because it won't change the logic or outcome.